# How to update nested entity with api platform?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have 2 entities:

Parent:

```php
<?php
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        'post',
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get',
        'put',
    ],
    attributes: [
        'validation_groups' => ['edition'],
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['r-parent']],
        'denormalization_context' => ['allow_extra_attributes' => false, 'groups' => ['w-parent']],
    ],
    routePrefix: '/api',
)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ParentRepository::class)]
class Parent
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    #[Groups(['r-parent'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'parent', targetEntity: Child::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], orphanRemoval: true)]
    #[Assert\Valid(groups: ['edition'])]
    #[Groups(['r-parent', 'w-parent'])]
    private array|PersistentCollection|ArrayCollection $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Child:

```php
<?php
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        'post',
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get',
        'put',
    ],
    attributes: [
        'validation_groups' => ['edition'],
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['r-child']],
        'denormalization_context' => ['allow_extra_attributes' => false, 'groups' => ['w-child']],
    ],
    routePrefix: '/api',
)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ChildRepository::class)]
class Child
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    #[Groups(['r-parent'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 1)]
    #[Groups(['r-parent', 'w-parent'])]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Parent::class, inversedBy: 'children')]
    #[Groups(['r-child'])]
    private ?Establishment $establishment = null;
}
```

## POST

I can create a `Parent` with his child:

`POST` `/api/parents`

```json
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Child 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Child 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```json
{
  "@id": "/api/parents/1",
  "children": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/children/1",
      "name": "Child 1"
    },
    {
      "@id": "/api/children/2",
      "name": "Child 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

## PUT

Now I want to be able to update the names of my children using the `PUT` endpoint of my `Parent`, something like:

`PUT` `/api/parents/1`

```json
{
  "children": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/children/1",
      "name": "Child 1.2"
    },
    {
      "@id": "/api/children/2",
      "name": "Child 2.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Result:

```json
{
  "@id": "/api/parents/1",
  "children": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/children/1",
      "name": "Child 1.2"
    },
    {
      "@id": "/api/children/2",
      "name": "Child 2.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I got:

```json
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Extra attributes are not allowed (\"@id\" is unknown).",
  "trace": [
//    ...
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I ended up by creating this packagae: https://packagist.org/packages/lenny4/doctrine-merge-persistent-collection-bundle

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 'id' instead of '@id'. '@id' it's a hydrated property form API Platform